# New light switch not working

Tags: wiring, switch

My old light switch in a bedroom stopped working, and only worked when the switch was pushed and held in the on position.

I purchased another single pole switch. Upon taking the old switch out, I Noticed there were 5 wires...two black, two white, and a ground bare. There are two sets of wires coming into the wall box...one set of wires has the white hot, black, and ground. The other wire has the same three, but no electricity (which I assume turns on my overhead lights in the bedroom.)

The old switch had two side screws used, two push back connectors (where a wire is simply pushed into the hole in the back of the switch), and the ground wire on a screw.

The new switch I wired with the white hot into the push-back, the one black into the other push back, then one white and one black on the side screws, with the ground connected. No lights came on. I tried putting the hot white wire and black wire onto the side screws (swapping the wires between the push back and side screws), and the other white and black wires into the push backs, with no lights working again.

Not sure what this means, but between the white and black wire, I’m getting around 53v. When I put the multimeter on the metal case (near the actual switch) and the black wire, I’m getting 120v. Any help would be appreciated!

[image][image]

Comment: Also, just to be clear I just took the wires off the side screws right before I took the picture.

Comment: How many screws did the old switch have?  Not counting the ground screw.

Comment: you have the colors mixed up ... black is hot .... white is neutral

Comment: STOP EXPIRMENTING and engage the services of a professional electrician

Comment: It baffles me why people don't take a picture BEFORE, they take the old item out. I do this for just about every thing I ever do, so I remember where everything was before and can hook it back the way it was. If that doesn't work, then I have to figure it out. But generally, whites are always nutted together, and blacks go to the switch, but on an outlet, then you do have whites and blacks to the outlet, on opposite sides.

Comment: **You can't reuse backstab connections**.  Once you pull out the wire, that backstab is "sprung"/damaged, and it is not reliable to hold another wire.  (not that it was reliable before, backstabs are the #1 cause of wiring failure that we see).  So once you yank out any backstab, you have two choices: 1) throw the device in the trash, or 2) never use backstabs and only use screws, which moots the issue and makes connections more reliable too.  What do you do when 2 wires need to go to 1 screw?  That's a good question...

Comment: Typically when you have a backstab connection *quite near* a screw terminal, the backstab and screw are internally connected to each other.  Was that the case on the original switch?

Comment: The original switch has one screw on one side, one screw on the other side, two backstab connections. The new switch has two screws on one side, and two backstab connections.

Comment: I did this again, nutting the two whites together, pigtailing both grounds, and one black on one screw and one black on the other. Lights still won’t come on. Switched the blacks around just in case, and still nothing.

Comment: The old switch had only one ground connected, and both whites and both blacks connected, one each screw, one each backstab connection. Not sure where I’m going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

### The whites aren't hot, they're *neutral*

The white wires here are not hot wires at all, they're the *neutral* wires that return current back to the power company.  So:

- Blacks go to switch terminals (one is the always-hot, the other the switched-hot to the light)
- Whites get nutted together to provide a neutral return to the panel/power company service
- Grounds get nutted to each other and to a bare pigtail going to the switch's green ground screw.